# What is the HTML code for "CE" mark?

Tags: html, unicode

I need to put the [CE mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking) in some text in HTML, but I have not been able to find it in the character lookup tables.

Is this symbol something similar to TM, Registered, Copy Right etc.? If so, does it have a HTML code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CE mark, or CE marking as it is now officially called, has not been encoded as a character. Thus, the only way to include it in an HTML document is to use graphics of some kind, such as an image or drawing on a canvas.

The CE marking is a specific graphic to be printed or otherwise permanently included in products according to EU legislation. It has no use in documents other than documents discussing this symbol, so there was no need to encode it as a text character. In contrast, e.g. the registered sign ”®” is widely used in advertisements, manuals, and other texts as attached to a name to indicate it as a registered trade mark.

Comment: So there is no need to mention a product is CE certified? In that case how does one convey that their product meets the CE requirements? Just asking to see if there is an alternative way to achieve the same result.

Comment: The CE marking as such does not involve certification. It is a mandatory marking in some products in some situations, not in information about products. If you are marketing some product in some countries, there is normally no reason to proclaim that the product is being sold legally; in fact, it could look suspicious.

But if you wish to inform about the presence of the CE marking in a product, you can include a photo of the image so that the marking is visible.

Comment: We could write a proposal to Unicode and request the CE Marking to be encoded at U+E091.

Comment: U+E091 is a Private Use Area codepoint, which means that it is for use by private agreements only. The Unicode Consortium will never assign a character for it. But if they decided to include a character for CE marking, they would surely find a codepoint for it. To make them seriously consider that, you would need to demonstrate existing usage of CE mark in *texts*.

Answer (score 3):

The Conformité Européen (CE) logo has prescribed layout and dimensions (https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking_en). Logo examples can be downloaded using Google images.

When and how to use it on ratings labels is contained in the Machinery Directive (2006/42/EC) and various other EU directives.

You register your Statement of Conformity and get a registration number, which can be searched online by anyone.

The label statement should appear thus: CE Approval Number: CE  MXX  0126, where MXX is the year of manufacture; M17, M18, etc., and 0126 is the manufacturer's number. MXX goes in a square box.

The CE logo and certificate number go next to the manufacturers address on the label, and/or packaging.

In documentation, the format would be 'European Conformity (CE)' the first time it is used in a section, then 'CE' for the rest of the section.

Under IPR, only the prescribed format and use is allowed, so read up before you use it incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for the CE Marking. You can use it by typing the Ukrainian letters С & Є. Type it like this: С Є

Comment: Not even close. The letters look rather different from the style of letters C and E in the CE marking. The CE marking is a specific graphic, so it is pointless to try to get something resembiing it using characters, when you can simply use an image.